# PHP add element in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I add an element to this multidimensional array?

```
Array
(
    [Items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Item] => 211
                    [Unit] => 11
                    [Quantity] => 2
                    [GST] => True
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Item] => 210
                    [Unit] => 11
                    [Quantity] => 1
                    [GST] => True
                )

        )

)
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($data['Items'] as $Item) {
    array_push($Item, 'User' => 1);
}
```

Comment: Forget about `array_push()` and learn how to [access and modify array elements using the square brackets syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems with your loop.

First, this syntax `array_push($Item, 'User' => 1);` is wrong, array_push adds a value to the array and the `=>` should only be used inside arrays. Instead of `array_push` you can use `$arr[] = 'your value'` and the result will be similar.

Second, for the `$Item` variable to hold the added value outside the loop you need to pass it by reference, like this:

```
foreach ($data['Items'] as &$Item) {
    $Item['User'] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what you exactly want but simply you can add like this

```
$array = Array
(
    'Items' => Array
        (
            '0' => Array
                (
                    "Item" => 211,
                    "Unit" => 11,
                    "Quantity" => 2,
                    "GST" => True
                )

        )

);

$array["Items"][0]["new_value"] = "Some Value";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must access to the array with the `[` `]`, e.g. this code insert a new item with key 2:

```
$data['Items'][] = array([Item] => 234
                [Unit] => 22
                [Quantity] => 3
                [GST] => False);
```

Or, if you need to add an element to every Item:

```
foreach ($data['Items'] as $k)
{
    $k[] = array([Item] => 234
                    [Unit] => 22
                    [Quantity] => 3
                    [GST] => False);
}
```

Read here for more info: [PHP's Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try that way :

```
<?php
$prod_id=1;$size="s";$colour="red"; 
$foo["cart"] = array (  
    1 => array (  
        array ('size'=>'S','color'=>'white')  
        ,  
        array ('size'=>'M','color'=>'red')  
    ),  
    2 => array (  
        array ('size'=>'S','color'=>'black')  
        ,  
        array ('size'=>'XL','color'=>'royal')  
    )  
); 
array_push($foo["cart"][$prod_id], array ("quantity" => 1, "size" => $size, "colour" => $colour));   
print_r($foo);
?>
```